# comparing operands xpath assertion expression with expected result in soapUI

Tags: xpath, soapui

I'm using soapUI 5 (non pro) and all i need is to validate(assert) a number is greater than zero in the expected result section. So this means

1) in XPath expression(Xpath match) I am declaring the below (I need to remove all text and only have numbers then check that number is greater than zero)

```
replace(//OUTBOUND_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_CONTENT, '[^0-9]','')
```

2) All i want to do in expected result is =!0 or number>0 so i attempted

`${=!0}` but doing that brings back a boolean T/F. I'm really lost :(

Comment: May be you put the xml snippet from your response, that will be of help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `${=!0}` is not working as you expect. In SOAPUI this kind of expressions `${=expression}` are executed as groovy script so really SOAPUI is executing `!0` which is result is true and this is the expected result. This is why SOAPUI throws `replace..., expecting [true]`.

I think that it's better to change you `XPath expression` to evaluate directly if your expression is `>0`:

`number(replace(//OUTBOUND_MESSAGE.MESSAGE_CONTENT, '[^0-9]',''))>0`

And as expected result simply set `true`.

[image]