# SOAPUI XPATH assert AND test

Tags: xpath, soapui

Using community soapui 5.2.1.
Can I use an XPATH assertion to test a number is between two values?
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872959/comparing-operands-xpath-assertion-expression-with-expected-result-in-soapui) shows how to do one logical test.
But I'd like to store the value in a variable and test on an AND condition.
Something like (psuedo code):

> declare namespace ns1='http://my.space/XML/output/6.1';
>
> testme=//ns1:items-section[1]/ns1:results/@total_items;
>
> testme > 100 && testme < 200;

If this can't be done, options i see are:

- retrieving the attribute twice (guess that's not performant)
- reverting to script assertion (more complex )
- buy NG PRO ( more expensive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO generally if you want to apply a pseudo code for assertion purpose I prefer to use *script assertion* since in *SOAPUI Groovy script assertion* gives you a lot of flexibility.

However your case seems short, and you're only worried about to avoid perform twice the same *XPath*; then you can use a option which is not in your list: ***XQuery Match*** *assertion*. The *XQuery* expression could be:

```
declare namespace ns1='http://my.space/XML/output/6.1';
declare variable $testme := //ns1:items-section[1]/ns1:results/@total_items;
($testme > 100 and $testme < 200)
```

Note the use of `and` instead of `&&`.

Also you can simplify your *XPath* expression using `*` for namespaces:

```
declare variable $testme := //*:items-section[1]/*:results/@total_items;
($testme > 100 and $testme < 200)
```

This will return in the expected result:

`<xml-fragment>true</xml-fragment>` or `<xml-fragment>false</xml-fragment>` depends on the `$testme` value.

Hope this helps,

Comment: works great! Thanks for the workspace tip, my first try was without a namespace and soapui didn't like it.

Comment: @Catweazle nice to help you `:)`